# How to round off a double number to 2 decimal places in c++

Tags: c++

I need to write a simple program, which would round off double number to just 2 decimal places. Example:
input - 0.3333333, 124.132001
output - 0.33, 124.13

Comment: [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) has what you want.

Comment: How are you outputting numbers now?  `printf` or `cout` or something more exotic?

Comment: `cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 0.3333333 << "\n";`

Comment: Try this: [`std::set_precision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: Question is, did OP meant to print rounded value (note, it always will be rounded down)  or to actually round off. The latter is non-trivial and in certain context requires ditching floating point values as a type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::set_precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) as in

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 0.3333333;
```